Unsupported authentication scheme 'WorkloadIdentityFederation' for Azure endpoint
I have release pipelines which were working perfectly fine till 3 days back, no change was made, but now i am getting below error
Unsupported authentication scheme 'WorkloadIdentityFederation' for Azure endpoint.

Potentially, somebody converted existing Service Connection from a different type to WorkloadIdentityFederation type.

Hi, if you use a new service connection, which is not the workload identity federation service connection, will the error disappear? By the way, can you share the task name where you get the error?

The error message indicates that the Azure Resource Manager service connection in your release pipeline is converted to a workload identity federation service connection and the task in your release pipeline doesn't support it. See the convert steps here.
Currently, not all the pipeline tasks support the workload identity federation service connection. You can check the table that lists workload identity federation support for tasks included with Azure DevOps.  For tasks installed from the Marketplace, contact the extension publisher for support.
To solve the error, you can create and use a new Azure Resource Manager service connection.
If the task has a new version that support the workload identity federation service connection, please change the task version. For example, I know that for Terraform Task, only the TerraformTaskV4@4 supported the workload identity federation service connection.
